# How to access a custom collection property by its property name

Tags: c#

I want to implement a custom collection that contains instances of my class.

This is my class, a bit simplified here.

```
public class Property : IComparable<Property> 
{
   public string Name;
   public string Value;
   public string Group;
   public string Id;
   ...
   ...

   public int CompareTo(Property other)
   {
      return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
   }
}
```

I am adding instances of Property to a List collection

```
Public List<Property> properties;
```

I can iterate through properties or access a specific property through the index position.

I want to however be able to access the property by its Name such that

```
var myColor = properties["Color"].Value;
```

and I do not have an efficient way to do this. I assume that properties should be written as a custom list collection class to achieve this. Does anyone have a code sample I can look at?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you still wish to be able to access them using the index? Or is access by name enough?

Comment: Accessing by name and iterating through the collection are more common than accessing the object by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest methods were already mentioned, but I see two:

**Method 1**
Convert to dictionary and lookup there.

```
var props = properties.ToDictionary( x => x.Name );
Property prop = props["some name"];
```

**Method 2**
Create your own collection type which would support indexing
by your arbitrary type.

```
public class PropertyCollection : List<Property>
{
    public Property this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (Property prop in this)
            {
                if (prop.Name == name)
                    return prop;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and use this collection instead

```
PropertyCollection col = new PropertyCollection();
col.Add(new Property(...));
Property prop = col["some name"];
```

Comment: Method 2 is probably what I am looking for. Will the iteration have any significant impact over using the index? My collection will not hold more than 30 instances of Property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, Property> properties = new Dictionary<string, Property>();

//you add it like that:
properties[prop.Name] = prop;

//then access it like that:
var myColor = properties["Color"];
```

Comment: The name, value is a simplified version of my Property class. I should have mentioned it, it has other members.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary<string,Property>` for this purpose. The key will be the property name and the value will be the Property instance itself.